# Javascript won't add class to sidemenu when it has a button element as a child

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, addeventlistener

My side-menu has a close (X) button that was initially an <a> element. I changed it to a <button> instead, but now the side-menu refuses to open. The strange thing is, the 'toggle' class that is being added to my side-menu container when the button is clicked, is not added when there's a button inside its container. When I revert it back to <a> element, it works again. This baffles my mind. In the inspector, I can see Chrome trying to add the class to the HTML, as the lines turns purple. [Here's an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuAM.png) Yet, the 'toggle' class isn't being added, as if something is preventing it from happening?

HTML

```
<header>
<button id="mobile-expand" class="menu-icon mobile" aria-controls="primary navigation" aria-expanded="">
    <svg></svg>
</button>


<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button id="mobile-close" class="menu-exit" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria-expanded="">
        <svg></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.main-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100dvh;
  z-index: 999;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1), width 0.3s ease;
}

.main-navigation.toggled {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.menu-exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 22px;
  z-index: 997;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const htmlElement = document.documentElement;
    const primaryNav = document.querySelector('.main-navigation');
    const navToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');

    const openSideMenu = function () {
        htmlElement.classList.add('no-scroll');
        primaryNav.classList.add('toggled');
        navToggle.classList.add('toggled');
        menuOverlay.classList.add('opaque');
        console.log('hello this works');
    }
    navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    openSideMenu();
    });
});
```

- Removing all unnecessary JS, classes, aria-controls and HTML to see if nothing was conflicting
- Reverting the <button> back to <a>. When I do this, everything magically works again.
- Checking the console for any errors, which are there are none.

Comment: Well where's the "menu-icon" element?

Comment: ... and have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: I added the menu-icon for clarification! The console shows no errors.

Comment: Is the php relevant to this problem?

Comment: Yea what is the actual in-the-browser content of that `<nav>` block?

Comment: Because `page-overlay` element isn't here either.

Comment: I removed the PHP and added the menu the code, without the links for brevity. The page-overlay is disabled for now, I have removed it as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Besides the inspector, are there any other "symptoms" that the `toggled` class isn't being added? When I log the className for both the `primaryNav` and `navToggle`, it's listed with both. And only `primaryNav/.main-navigation` has any CSS related to the toggle class.

Comment: I tried to log the className as you suggested. When I add console.log(primaryNav.className) at the END of the openSideMenu() function, it it logs 'toggled'. When I add it as the FIRST line of the openSideMenu() function and click it a few times, it is gone. And I've disabled the closeSideMenu() function and all other javascript code, so the 'toggled' should not have been removed. I have no idea how this is possible.

Comment: *and click it a few times*: how are you doing this? `navToggle` disappears as soon as I click it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with your JavaScript code not properly selecting the close button when it's changed to a  element. Here's what you can do to fix it

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const htmlElement = document.documentElement;
    const primaryNav = document.querySelector('.main-navigation');
    const navToggle = document.querySelector('#mobile-close'); // Updated selector
    const menuOverlay = document.querySelector('.page-overlay');

    const openSideMenu = function () {
        htmlElement.classList.add('no-scroll');
        primaryNav.classList.add('toggled');
        navToggle.classList.add('toggled');
        menuOverlay.classList.add('opaque');
        console.log('hello this works');
    }

    navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        openSideMenu();
    });
});
```

Make sure you have updated the selector for navToggle to #mobile-close

Comment: This is not the problem, the OP has updated the question.

Comment: Hi ESSAM_MOHAMED, thanks for taking the time to reply. I tried what you suggested, but sadly it still doesn't work.